# What is the use of parameterizing a ssis connection manager (project with single package)?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Suppose that the ssis project has only 1 package and I don't want to make use of environments.

What will be the benefit of parameterizing the connection manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of parameterising your connection managers is that should you ever change your data source (e.g. the server/database is moved internally or you move to the cloud) you can update the connection without downloading, editing and then re-deploying the SSIS project.

The time taken to set up a parameterised connection is measured in single digit minutes and therefore isn't exactly a significant cost to hedge against potential work in the future.

This is especially pertinent should your SSIS estate start to grow over time.  If each time you think "It's only the one extra connections" you'll eventually get to the point where you're saying "Parameterising the other 6 connections will take too long now, I'll do it later."  If you do then ever have to update them all, you'll have to do all of them manually, which will take a lot longer than if you just parameterised from the start.

Comment: You can setup the connection manager settings by right clicking on the deployed package in sql server and entering the values under connection manager. Why do you need parameters when this is supported by default?

Comment: For the likely event that you end up with more than the one reference to that connection within your SSIS project.  It is about setting up your environment in a scalable manner from the start.  If your environment grows in the future, you'll be glad you made it more scalable initially when the time comes.

Comment: Yes true. So other than project having more than 1 package or the need to use multiple environments, is there any other benefit of parameterizing the connection manager?

Comment: At this point you are putting more effort into finding a justification *not* to do it than it would have taken to just take the more scalable and flexible option.  I personally think you should simply develop your environments as you would like to have them going forwards, which for me means doing things like parameterising connections as it makes life easier in the future, which you can't predict. At worst, you wasted 2 minutes doing the parameterisation.